# How to make Shiny leaflet map reac to change in Input value R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have the below ui.R and server.R

I have a simple dataset with 3 columns: Type of person, Longitude, Latitude

I want the Leaflet Map to react to a change in "Type of Person" <<< **This is where i am stuck.** 
I know i need to use some sort of observeEvent but not sure how to implement this

Thank You

**ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "Selector",
              label = "Please Select Type of Person",
              choices = c("Please Select:",
                          "Type A",
                          "Type B"),
              selected = "Please Select:"),

  leafletOutput("myMap")
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles()%>%
      addMarkers(data=SampleData,
                 ~Longitude,
                 ~Latitude)
  })

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want your map to do, but it sounds like you are looking for `leafletProxy`. For example, suppose you want to clear your markers and add new ones. When you use `addMarkers`, be sure to include the `group` parameter:

(Edited to provide a complete reproducible example. Note that the answer I gave previously is unchanged, I just added the data and the rest of the shiny app structure. Note also that the 'Please Select:' part is treated as a valid choice here, there are better ways to handle the select, but that is not what this question is about.)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

SampleData <- data.frame(type = c('Type A', 'Type B', 'Type A', 'Type B'),
                         Longitude = c(80.1, 80.2, 80.3, 80.4),
                         Latitude = c(40.1, 40.2, 40.3, 40.4))


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "Selector",
              label = "Please Select Type of Person",
              choices = c("Please Select:",
                          "Type A",
                          "Type B"),
              selected = "Please Select:"),

  leafletOutput("myMap")
)


server <- function(input,output){

  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles()%>%
      addMarkers(data=SampleData,
                 ~Longitude,
                 ~Latitude,
                 group = "myMarkers")
  })


  observeEvent(input$Selector, {
    leafletProxy("myMap") %>%
      clearGroup("myMarkers") %>%
      addMarkers(data = SampleData[SampleData$type == input$Selector, ],
                 ~Longitude,
                 ~Latitude,
                 group = "myMarkers")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Will try this out shortly. What I want is: when user selects ‘Type B’ for example, the leaflet map only shows the locations of all the Type B people. Is that clearer ?

Comment: Ok, editing answer to give a little more based on that.

Comment: Nice, this works! would you be kind enough to explain why this works and what the the above code is doing?

Comment: Check out the documentation for `?leafletProxy`. It is specifically designed for Shiny and doing exactly this sort of thing. See also https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html.

Comment: great thanks! is it easy to add another observeEvent if i add another dataset?

Comment: Hi Brain, I have had to release this as a right answer. I have noticed it is not actually changing the selection at all and no matter if i select "TYPE A", or "TYPE B", the map will show the output for both types

Comment: The answer I gave works, it appears you are having problems with subsetting your data. This is why you should give a minimum reproducible example. Since you have not, I will edit my answer to provide one.